# Windows Service Fails gives connection error when sending messages to event hub

Tags: c#, azure, windows-services, azureservicebus, azure-eventhub

I am having an interesting problem.

I have deployed a windows service to an azure virtual machine.  This machine holds a windows service that will send messages to an azure event hub.

This issue only started occurring on this specific VM and her sister (as i was provisioning for horizontal scale-ability).  I just provisioned it, and installed the service on it.  The same service, when run from my local machine works fine (same code base, same builds, same config... literally a copy and paste job) and I have access to the internet from the vm (i checked via internet explorer)

This same service worked fine on an older azure vm that I decommissioned. This older vm was NOT SETUP BY ME, so its possible I am missing something on the new one that I failed to account for.

I am unsure what exactly to put on here but here is the relevant code I am using for the send.

```
public class MessageSender
{
    private static readonly string EventHubName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EventHubName_v2_0"];
    private static EventHubClient _client = EventHubClient.CreateFromConnectionString(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EventHubConnectionString"], EventHubName);

    /// <summary>
    /// Send a message to the EventHub if the app configuration has cloud messaging enabled and the event hub connection strings present
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="message">The contents of the message being sent.</param>
    /// <param name="clientId">The unique id of the client associated with this message.</param>
    public static void Send(string message, string clientId)
    {
        var eventProperties = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            {Constants.LoggingProperties.MO_MESSAGE_CONTENTS, message},
            {Constants.LoggingProperties.MO_MESSAGE_DESTINATION, EventHubName},
            {Constants.LoggingProperties.CLIENT, clientId}
        };

        var startTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
        var endTime = null as DateTime?;

        try
        {
            var data = new EventData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message));
            _client.Send(data); // <-- fails here
            endTime = DateTime.UtcNow;

        }
        catch (Exception eventHubEx)
        {
            Log.Instance.TrackException(eventHubEx);
            Console.WriteLine(eventHubEx.Message);
...
}
```

relevant app.config stuff

```
<add key="EventHubConnectionString" value="Endpoint=sb://xxxxx.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=xxxx;SharedAccessKey=xxxx" />

<add key="EventHubName_v2_0" value="xxxx" />
```

these values are identical to the values that are from my local machine.  I just changed the name of the file to match the executable name.

At this point my only thought is that it could be a networking issue but I am unsure what I need to check to verify it, or if there is a way (simple or otherwise) to check to ensure the connectivity.

Any other ideas will be entertained as well.

Thanks for any help you can offer.

Comment: Is there a firewall in play?

Comment: its possible there is a firewall issue.  The azure vnet and subnet is there but its the same group as every other service we use (and they all still work with event hub).  The local windows vm has a firewall on it as well.  I will attempt to disable it and see if that helps

Comment: i disabled the firewall on the offending VM and it's still not working. Thanks for the idea though.